# howto create a filesystem like /proc?

Tags: c, configuration, procfs

I would like to create a pseudo filesystem like /proc to access an applications configuration.

How could i achieve this or where could i find some introductory documentation about it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/). This is particularly easy with high-level language bindings, such as [fuse-python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuse-python/0.2).

Comment: cause of the lack of a suitable fuse abstraction i wrote my own c-library. if one needs to use its own proc like filesystem have a look at https://github.com/VRciF/procfuse and the documentation https://github.com/VRciF/procfuse/wiki/ProcFuse-Documentation - hth

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want to have a look at [sysfs](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.34/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt)

Comment: I thought that sysfs was for accessing kernel data, and wasn't suitable for applications which presumably live in user space.

Comment: the same thing happens with /proc filesystem. It is designed to export to user space applications kernel internal information.

Comment: Strange, I guess I'm not reading the question correctly. It seems like the OP wants to access configuration data for a running user space application, not a kernel thread.